# Can you identify this bevelled grey 2x1 piece?

Tags: part-identification, moc

I found this incredible MOC of the Ghost In The Shell robot and found a piece I have never seen before.  Is it a LEGO piece and, if so, can you help me identify it?

[image]

Link to the image source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/coleblaq/31984689954/in/faves-43378406@N08/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's [99563 LegoMinifig, Utensil Gold Ingot (Bar)](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99563&name=Minifig,%20Utensil%20Gold%20Ingot%20(Bar)&category=%5BMinifig,%20Utensil%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) in Light Bluish Grey.

[image]

Originally used for Gold pieces, nowadays regularly found as bricks and other wall decorations, for example on the ground floor of [10251 Brick Bank](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10251-1&name=Brick%20Bank&category=%5BModular%20Buildings%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D).

[image]